# How to print the last digit of floating part of a number?

Tags: java, c, floating-point

I am finding an easy way to print the last floating point digit of a number.`For EG : 33.44 ans - 4`
.

However, I managed it in `JAVA` easily, but I am a `C/C++` beginner.An SSCCE for `JAVA` code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Test{
 public static void main(String[] args){
 Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    Float f;
    f=scan.nextFloat();
    System.out.println(f);
    String g=f.toString(f);
    System.out.println(g.charAt(g.length()-1));
 }
}
```

I don't think it will be something that easy in `C/C++`. Any logics/solutions?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, either in Java or C/C++.  The rightmost decimal digit of a `float` is not what you'd expect, in general; see http://floating-point-gui.de/.  It sounds like what you need is the last character of your input string.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: If only you *could* print out the real last digit...I've been meaning to read the final digit of `pi` for a while now.

Comment: @downvoter Please give reasons for down-vote :)

Comment: @joeyrohan: In Java, and in C or C++ implementations which use IEEE-754 binary floating-point, which is most of them, there is no floating-point number which equals 33.44. Thus, this question uses incorrect premises; if you set `f = 33.44` for a `Float f`, `f` is not set to 33.44, and its last digit is not 4. It may be that what you actually want is either that last digit of some numeral (a string, not a `Float`, possibly one entered by the user) or the last digit of the result of converting a `Float` to a decimal numeral with some constraints, such as that the result has 6 significant digits.

Comment: If `x` is a finite binary floating-point number, then, if `x` is an integer, the last significant digit in its decimal numeral is `fmod(x, 10)`. If `x` is not an integer, then the last signifiant digit in its decimal numeral is 5. **Every** finite binary floating-point number with a fractional part ends in “5”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok thanks for the info . Questions can be improved with suggestions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in an equivalent manner, you would do something like (not compiled to check)

```
int getLast( double value )
{
  int rc;
  char buf[64];
  rc=snprintf(buf,64,"%f",value);
  // TODO:: check rc is in the range 1-64 
  return buf[rc-1]-'0';
}
```

You should probably check the result of rc and use `strtol` rather than the ascii hack of `-'0'`, but you get the picture.

if you want the rightmost non-0 value, the return line should be replace with

```
char *x=&(buf[rc-1]);
while( *x=='0' ) x--;
return *x-'0';
```

Comment: Also, I have seen `sprintf`, so in what way it's different from `snprintf` ?

Comment: the 'n' versions of the printf (and related) codes will write at most N (where N is the second parameter) characters. You should pretty much always use these (to avoid buffer overflows) unless you know better

Comment: When called with `getLast(33.44)`, this code returns 0. Why was this answer accepted?

Comment: I haven't tried the code too.I just got an idea how to go about things :)

Comment: Just ran it through gdb.
The code does work, it's just the right most digit of 33.44 as interpreted by the compiler is a 0 - as the value is stored as '33.440000'

Comment: @OliverMatthews 33.440000 is not a possible value of a float or double. All finite float or double numbers are exact finite binary fractions. 33.440000 is not - there is no pair of integers n and m such at 3.44 is n/m and m is a power of two.

Comment: @OliverMatthews: The compiler does not treat the float as 33.440000 or store it as 33.440000. You created this when you told it to convert it to a decimal numeral with six digits after the decimal point (the default of `%f`). With a different format, you would get a different answer. So this code merely produces the last digit of an arbitrary format conversion, not an inherent last digit of a number.

Comment: A fair point, i should have been clearer on where I was referring to it being 'stored' - the char array or the double.

Answer (score 2):

If the nominal value of a floating-point number is not an integer, unless the fractional part is *exactly* equal to 0.5, 0.25, or 0.75, the exact value of the fractional part will always end in 125, 375, 625, or 875.  In many cases, one isn't actually interested in the exact nominal value of the fractional part, but instead a rounded decimal representation.  In that case, the value of the "last" digit will depend upon how much one is willing to have the reported value differ from the number's exact nominal value (e.g. the `1.0f / 10.0f` is a `float` whose nominal value is exactly 1,342,173/13,421,728, i.e. 0.100000001490116119384765625.  The last digits of the exact nominal value are 625, but the number might also be interpreted as 0.1, or 0.1000000015, 0.10000000149, 0.10000000149012, etc. so one could justify 1, 5, 9, or 2 as being the "last" digit.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you(in C++) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 string float_data;
 cin>>float_data;
 int len = float_data.length();
 cout<<float_data.at(len-1)<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but the processing should be on the type `float/Float` :)

Comment: ok. I thought you just wanted to only print the last digit on the console.

Answer (score 0):

The below approach can be followed but it has limitation that the float value should not be very big.

```
void main()
{
int i, m;
float n;
printf("Enter the number n: ");
scanf("%f", &n);
m=(int)n;
i=(m % 10);
printf("last digit = %d", i);
}
```